# How do I add a background image and label to a UIBarButtonItem using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, uibarbuttonitem

I am referring to the icons that exist in the bottom of the iPhone Facebook app.
They have an image and a label underneath. How can I achieve this using Swift in Xcode 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a tab bar to your view. Then you can add tabs programmatically:

```
let firstImage = UIImage(named: "home-icon")
firstTabViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: firstImage, tag: 1)
```

Check out the excellent [Tab Bar Swift Tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/09/swift-swift-using-tab-bar-controllers-in-swift/) by Steve Lipton to learn how to do configure Tab Bars in a storyboard or programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This is a UITabBarController. See: [View Controller Catalog for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW1)